# Games not compatible with devices under android 8 .in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I update my android SDK version to 26 in android manifest. My games are not compatible with devices under android 8. What should I do to be compatible with all versions of android?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the minimum SDK version in the Player Settings `Edit > Project Settings > Player`, then expand `Other Settings` [image]

NOTE: Lowering the minimum supported version means that certain features that are available only for Androind 8 and above will not work on lower versions.